# Is there a mini or compact keyboard option for iPhone apps?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I have an iPhone app that is showing a UIWebView which contains some fields.  I would like the keyboard to be more compact.  Is there any way to do this to make the keyboard use less real estate?

Comment: What?! It's not small enough for you as-is?! :-O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not for a `UIWebview`, unless you want your customers to jailbreak there iDevices and get a custom keyboard from Cydia.

However, you could create a custom keyboard and hook that up to a custom view. That would make for a lot of work, but could be done, if you were willing to put the effort into it.